# What is the most ruby-ish way of accessing nested hash values at arbitrary depths?

Tags: ruby, hash, hash-of-hashes

Given a hash such as:

```rb
AppConfig = {
  'service' => {
    'key' => 'abcdefg',
    'secret' => 'secret_abcdefg'
  },
  'other' => {
    'service' => {
      'key' => 'cred_abcdefg',
      'secret' => 'cred_secret_abcdefg'
    }
  }
}
```

I need a function to return service/key in some cases and other/service/key in other cases.  A straightforward way is to pass in the hash and an array of keys, like so:

```rb
def val_for(hash, array_of_key_names)
  h = hash
  array_of_key_names.each { |k| h = h[k] }
  h
end
```

So that this call results in 'cred_secret_abcdefg':

```rb
val_for(AppConfig, %w[other service secret])
```

It seems like there should be a better way than what I've written in val_for().

Comment: what should happen if a intermediate key is not found? and if the last key is not there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```rb
def val_for(hash, keys)
  keys.reduce(hash) { |h, key| h[key] }
end
```

This will raise an exception if some intermediate key is not found. Note also that this is completely equivalent to `keys.reduce(hash, :[])`, but this may very well confuse some readers, I'd use the block.

Comment: Sure, it's up to the caller in my implementation to know what the config keys are.  Thanks!

Comment: Yea, yours is really better :).

Answer (score 6):

```
%w[other service secret].inject(AppConfig, &:fetch)
```

Comment: oh, indeed, and you can even write `:fetch`. This will fail also if the last key is not found, but that seems ok for the OP.

Comment: Your comment makes my answer look like it was written after you added the symbol to proc solution to your answer.

Comment: I am puzzled, I +1'd your answer and commented it with "oh, indeed" precisely to show that I had forgotten about this `inject` simplification and I wanted to give credit before editing my answer! Apparently I failed in my intention :-(

Comment: At first, I did not understand what you meant by "even" in the comment. It implies it is compared to something. Then I realized that your comment makes sense only after reading the edited part of your answer. This looked like assuming the reader will look at your answer, then read mine as a variant of it. But now I understand your intention.

Comment: Ok. With the "even" I meant you can simplify it a bit more and drop the `&`, `inject` accepts a symbol so the `Symbol#to_proc` trick is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
appConfig = {
  'service' => {
    'key' => 'abcdefg',
    'secret' => 'secret_abcdefg'
  },
  'other' => {
    'service' => {
      'key' => 'cred_abcdefg',
      'secret' => 'cred_secret_abcdefg'
    }
  }
}

def val_for(hash, array_of_key_names)
  eval "hash#{array_of_key_names.map {|key| "[\"#{key}\"]"}.join}"
end

val_for(appConfig, %w[other service secret]) # => "cred_secret_abcdefg"
```

Comment: Thanks Andres, but eval'ing a string and using escape characters isn't much prettier than what I originally wrote. :\

Answer (score 1):

Ruby 2.3.0 introduced [a new method called `dig`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-dig) on both `Hash` and `Array` that solves this problem entirely.

```
AppConfig.dig('other', 'service', 'secret')
```

It returns `nil` if the key is missing at any level.